# Polynomial $g:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ with no critical point may have no root

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, polynomials

Version 1 (solved): If $g$ : $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is a polynomial, $Dg(x)$ is non-degenerate for every $x$, then there exists $x$, such that $g(x)=0$.
Version 2: If $f$ : $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a polynomial, $D^2f(x)$ is non-degenerate for every $x$, then $f(x)$ has at least one critical point.
The problem is how to prove or disprove Version 1. The result of Version 2 is what I need to prove another problem.

Comment: Is $f$ a map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ or  a map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. In the second case, what is the meaning of the *nondegeneracy* of $D^2f$?

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, f in version 2 should be a polynomial functional on R^n, which means f:R^n \rightarrow R.

Comment: In version 1, we can prove g is an open mapping. However, g maybe not a closed mapping.

Comment: Then version 2 should read: Version 2: If $f$ : $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a polynomial, $D^2f(x)$ is non-degenerate for every $x$, then $f$ has at least one critical point. (It is a consequence of version 1 if version 1 is true, not equivalent to version 1).

Comment: I did some changes. Thank you, Jean.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close: Both (1) and (2) are reasonable questions; a "yes" answer to (1) implies a "yes" answer to (2). My guess is that they are both false, though...

Comment: This reminds me of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38019/zeros-of-gradient-of-positive-polynomials

Answer (score 27):

The answer to question 1 appears to be "no". Pinchuk, in "[A counterexample to the strong real Jacobian conjecture](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02571929)" found a polynomial map $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\det(Dg)$ is nonvanishing, yet $g$ is not a diffemorphism. [Campbell](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9812032v1.pdf) and [Gwoździewicz](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903026) (independently) computed the image of Pinchuk's map and found that it omitted $(0,0)$.

I say apparently because their computations don't seem to agree! Campbell finds that the omitted points are $(0,0)$ and $(-1,-163/4)$; Gwoździewicz gets $(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. It's probably just a notational issue, but one should probably check their work carefully before relying on it.

Still thinking about question 2. Given the complexity of Pinchuk's example, this seems likely to be hard.

---

A few thoughts, no real progress, on the second question. If $D^2 f$ is nonsingular for all inputs, then the signature of $D^2 f$ is constant. The easiest case to think about is when $D^2 f$ is positive definite, in which case $f$ is convex. In this case, I will show that there is a point with $Df=0$.

It is well known that, when $f$ is convex, the image of $Df$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. (So, if it is well known, why can't I find a reference? I'm sure I read this in a textbook on the multivariate Legendre transform, but I can't figure out which one.) So, if $0 \not \in (Df)(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then by [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) there is a vector $\vec{v}$ such that $\langle \vec{v}, \cdot \rangle$ is positive on $(Df)(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So $f$ is strictly increasing on lines in direction $\vec{v}$. But the only convex strictly increasing polynomials are linear functions, so $f$ is linear on every line in direction $\vec{v}$.

Changing coordinates to assume that $\vec{v}$ is parallel to the $z_n$ axis, we deduce that $f$ is of the form $g(z_1, \ldots, z_{n-1}) z_n + h(z_1, \ldots, z_{n-1})$, for some $g$ which is always positive. If $D^2 g \neq 0$ at some point $(z_1,\ldots, z_{n-1})$, then either $D^2 f$ is non-positive-definite at $(z_1, \ldots, z_{n-1}, M)$ for $M$ very positive, or for $M$ very negative, contradicting our claim that $D^2 f$ is always positive definite. So $D^2 g=0$ and we conclude that $g$ is affine linear. But $g$ is always positive, so $g$ is a constant. In short, $f=z_n+h(z_1,\ldots, z_{n-1})$. But then the $n$-th column of $D^2 f$ vanishes, and $D^2 f$ is not invertible after all.

So there are no counter-examples with $D^2 f$ positive definite (or negative definite). But I never really thought there would be.

I'd love to see an analysis of the case of signature $+-$ on the plane. There definitely exist $f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ with $D^2 f$ of signature $+-$ everywhere: Just take the real part of some $h(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]$. But, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, $h'(z)$ has zeroes, so $D(\mathrm{Re}(h))$ vanishes in places.

Answer (score 3):

Building on David Speyer's answer, and as the problem (version 2) seems hard, I venture a (nonconclusive) argument for the case where $D^2f(x)$ has signature $+-$, on the plane. (I was meaning this as a comment, but it was too long...)

We probably can select smooth vector fields $e^+(x)$ and $e^-(x)$ in the positive and negative (orthogonal) directions (eigenvectors of $D^2f(x)$). This defines $X(s,t)\in\mathbb R^2$, $s,t\in\mathbb R$, with $\partial_s X=e^+(X)$ and $\partial_t X=e^-(X)$ (plus $X(0,0)=0$ for definiteness). Now $f(X(s,t))$ is strictly convex in $s$ and strictly concave in $t$, isn't it?

This doesn't prove $f$ has a saddle point (example $\mathrm{Re} (e^z)$), but maybe polynomials have something more that allows a "mountain pass lemma" to apply ?

EDIT That seemed plausible, but no: maybe there exists $X(s,t)$ such that $f(X(s,t))$ is convex in $s$ and concave in $t$, but *it cannot satisfy* $\partial_s X=e^+(X)$ and $\partial_t X=e^-(X)$, because the necessary integrability condition $(e^-\nabla) e^+=(e^+\nabla) e^-$ is (generically) incompatible with the orthogonality $e^+\cdot e^-=0$ (if I'm not mistaken again...)

Comment: Why can you choose the fields to commute?

Comment: I didn't mean "vector fields" as differential operators, just as functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself...

Comment: But then you want to integrate their flows to make $X$, right? So you need the fields to be integrable. For the record, I agree that this sounds like a promising approach, I'm just trying to get the details right.

Comment: You're right, we need to chose $e^\pm$ non unit to satisfy integrability. I guess it's possible. Won't be enough anyway...